# Unwanted characters when copying file using scatter/gather I/O (readv/writev)

Tags: c, operating-system, filesystems

I'm trying to build a program to copy existing content from an existing file to the new file using readv() and writev().
Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/uio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    int fs, fd; 

    ssize_t bytes_read, bytes_written;
    char buf[3][50]; 
    int iovcnt;
    struct iovec iov[3];
    int i;
    fs = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY); 
    if (fs == -1) {
        perror("open");
        return -1;
    }
    fd = open(argv[2], O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, S_IRWXU); 
    if (fd == -1) {
        perror("open");
        return 1;
    }

    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        iov[i].iov_base = buf[i];
        iov[i].iov_len = sizeof(buf[i]);
    }

    iovcnt = sizeof(iov) / sizeof(struct iovec);


    if ((bytes_read=readv(fs, iov, iovcnt)) != -1)
        if ((bytes_written=writev(fd, iov, iovcnt)) == -1)
            perror("error writev");
    printf("read: %ld bytes, write: %ld bytes\n", bytes_read, bytes_written);
    if (close (fs)) {
        perror("close fs");
        return 1;
    }
    if (close (fd)) {
        perror("close fd");
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Problem: Let's say I ran the program with argv[1] corresponding to the file called `file1.txt` and copied it to argv[2], let's say it's called as `hello.txt`.
This is the content  of `file1.txt`:

```
Ini adalah line pertamaS
Ini adalah line kedua
Ini adalah line ketiga
```

When I ran the program, the new created file specified in argv[2] were filled by unwanted characters such as \00.
Output after running the program:

```
Ini adalah line pertamaS
Ini adalah line kedua
Ini adalah line ketiga
\00\00\FF\B5\F0\00\00\00\00\00\C2\00\00\00\00\00\00\00W\D4\CF\FF\00\00V\D4\CF\FF\00\00\8D\C4|\8C\F8U\00\00\C8o\A6U\E5\00\00@\C4|\8C\F8U\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00 \C1|\8C\F8U\00\00`\D5\CF\FF
```

I suspect the main cause of the problem is unfitted size of `buf` array. I've already look up internet for the solutions and there are nothing to be found. Can anyone give me some enlightment to fix this problem? I tried to make the `buf` or `iov_len` to be variable-length but I couldn't find the right way to do it. Thanks everyone!

Comment: I don't understand.  Why are you writing 'iovcnt' bytes when you have 'bytes_read' from the previous line?

Answer (score 0):

`readv()` works with byte counts driven by each `.iov_len` and no special treatment for any content (like a line-feed). The `readv()` in the original posting is passed an array of (3) `struct iovec`, each with `.iov_len` set to 50.  After a successful `readv()`, the content of the local `buf[3][50]` would be:

buf[0] : first 50 bytes from the input file
buf[1] : next 20 bytes from the input file, then 30 bytes of uninitialized/leftover stack data
buf[2] : another 50 bytes of uninitialized/leftover stack data

The `writev()` reuses the same `struct iovec` array with all (3) `.iov_len` unchanged from 50, and writes 150 bytes as expected. The content of the output file has the first 70 bytes copied from the input file and 80 bytes of leftover stack data.  If the local `buf` was cleared before calling `readv()`, the output file would contain trailing NULLs.